# Python: I'm trying to use math contained in a variable

Tags: python

How can I make this:

```
a = '3,3,3,3'
b = a.replace(',','+')
print(b)
```

Have the output of 12?
I want the math inside the variable to be solved.

Comment: Your variable is referring to a `str` object.

Comment: Wow, thats a lot. I have no idea how that works, but thank you. I will look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = '3,3,3,3'
b = [int(el) for el in a.split(",")]
print(sum(b))
```

What is going on in the code:

1. separate input into a list of numbers.
2. cast strings in that list to ints
3. sum a list of ints.

Comment: It is wise not to use `eval` in this situation because of numerous security risks

Comment: @coderman1234, `eval` is not used here

Comment: This worked and is quite easy. Thanks!